# Within an English HTML Document - How to Reference Localized German for Search Engines?

Tags: html, localization

Having an english html page, is there a way to hint search bots to a localized alternative page?
I was thinking of something looking like this:

**index.html** (english):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
...
 <tag ref-lang="de" ref-page="index_de.html">
...
<body><p>Yes, English in here!</p></body>
</html>
```

and same in reverse

**index_de.html** (german):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="de" xml:lang="de">
...
 <tag ref-lang="en" ref-page="index.html">
...
<body><p>Ja, Deutsch hier drin!</p></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that search engines index your site in both languages? Add a sitemap.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is a link, visibly in the content (it helps people, too):

```
<span lang="de">Diese Seite auf Deutsch</span> / This page in German:
<a lang="de" hreflang="de" href="index_de.html" rel="alternate">
Bemerkungen über den Weltgeist</a>
```

You can also use a `link` element, but it is less certain that search engines use it, and human readers will most probably mess it, because it is invisible:

```
<link hreflang="de" href="index_de.html" rel="alternate" lang="de" title=
"Bemerkungen über den Weltgeist">
```

Answer (score 0):

Google has an identifier for this in sitemaps, you need to use hreflang="es" and rel="alternate"

See http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2620865

and

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182192